# Infer ip subnet using bit operations?

Tags: python, algorithm, math, networking, bit-manipulation

I have a bunch of IPV4 IPs, and I want to infer the subnet they belong to.

#...10101 00

#...10101 01

#...10101 10

#...10101 11

#...11111 is the subnet

One way I can think of is to forget about the "."s and treat the IPs as strings of 1s and 0s. Now, the only thing we need is to figure out which left-most block never changes. In my example, only the last two bits ever vary, so we know 11111111.11111111.11111111.111111 is the subnet.

Is there a clever way of determining the subnet this way, using bit operations? XOR's, etc.

Comment: Convert the IPv4 addresses to a list of 32-bit numbers. When you `&` them all together, any bit that's always 1 will remain 1, and any bits that change or are always 0 will be 0. When you `&` together all of the complements (`~`), any bit that's always 0 will be 1, and any bits that change or are always 1 will be 0. Finally `|` together the two results, then `&` with 0xffffffff, and you have the subnet mask as a 32-bit number.

Comment: Good idea. can't you just drop the however many consecutive right-most 0s, after &'ing all of the number together initially? After you identify the rightmost zeros, the leftmost component would be the number of 1s in the resulting mask. correct?

Comment: I guess that wouldn't work... the trailing zeros in the 'mask' slots wouldn't be picked up.

Comment: There is the possibility that the result is something like `11111111.11111111.11110110.00000000`. That could happen if the list of IP addresses doesn't have every IP address in the subnet. In that case, you need to start from the left-most bit and find the first 0. Then the subnet mask for the smallest subnet that contains all of the IPs has the 1's to the left of the first 0.